# DocuSign Prefill custom data fields

Tags: xml, templates, signature, docusignapi, datafield

I am attempting to request signature via a template and prefill some data fields using RESTAPI.  The only unsuccessful part of my quest is setting the data field value(s).  The envelope with document is sent with only the standard tags and their respective values.

Need some insight.

XML Body...

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <accountId><%= _accountID %></accountId>
   <emailSubject>DocuSign API - Request Template</emailSubject>
   <status>sent</status>
   <emailSubject>API Call for request from template</emailSubject>
   <emailBlurb>This comes from me</emailBlurb>
   <templateId><%= _templateID %></templateId>
   <templateRoles>
      <email>me@me.com</email>
      <name>Dean</name>
      <roleName>Signer</roleName>
      <recipientId>1</recipientId>
      <tabs>
         <textTabs>
            <tabLabel>CompanyName</tabLabel>
            <value>Dean Inc</value>
         </textTabs>
      </tabs>
   </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Were you able to figure out what was going wrong?  I am able to make the calls with the data fields filling in properly with this page: http://iodocs.docusign.com/?version=v2. However, the same calls aren't working from my code.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old and abandoned but I wanted to answer in case someone else stumbles across it. I ended up finding a very similar question here: [How to pre-fill tabs on a server template with the DocuSign API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600349/how-to-pre-fill-tabs-on-a-server-template-with-the-docusign-api).  The solution is to add another node in `<textTabs>` called `<text>` like the following:

```html
...
<tabs>
  <textTabs>
    <text>
      <tabLabel>CompanyName</tabLabel>
      <value>Dean Inc</value>
    </text>
  </textTabs>
</tabs>
...
```